# How to select options inside <select multiple="true"> from php array?

Tags: php, arrays, multi-select, dropdown

A field inside mysql table, when un-serialized, returns simple indexed array like:

```
$biz_cats = array(4, 5, 8, 12, 17);
```

I populate a select box by using all the categories by using:

```
SELECT `ID`, `cat_name` FROM `tbl_categories`
```

Code for the select box is below:

```
<select multiple="true" name="biz-cats[]" id="biz-cats" size="10">
    <option value="0">-- SELECT ONE --</option>

<?php
    // To populate all the categories to later-on allow user to select or de-select from
    if ($categories && is_array($categories)) {
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            echo '<option value="' . $category['ID'] . '">' . $category['cat_name']</option>';
        }
    }
?>
</select>
```

As this form is for Editing/Updating record (not to add new record), I need to make some options selected depending on the `$biz_cats`, I definitely has to select them exactly when the other fields of the form are poppulating with values inside database.

Comment: you can make option selected via `<option value="value" selected>text</option>`. Then work with if conditions, like `if(condition){ echo "selected";}`

Comment: I got your point. Thanks @TanuelMategi. Though it is very straight forward and easy solution but I was wondering about this from previous 36 hours. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your looking for `in_array`

```
if(in_array($category['ID'], $biz_cats)){ $selected = 'selected'; } else { $selected = ''; }
echo '<option value="' . $category['ID'] . '" ' . $selected . '>' . $category['cat_name']</option>';
```

Comment: Thank you @cmorrissey for coming to rescue me just with in 5 minutes.